# Specifying single space delimiter in perl

Tags: perl

The following `-F\\s` specifies *any* whitespace as a field delimiter for perl

```
$head simhash.txt | perl -F\\s  -lane  'print $F[1]'

FRM_REL2
..
```

What is the way to specify *only* a space (e.g. not tab or other whitespace) as the delimiter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"You can't use literal whitespace in the pattern." ([perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)).

So you have to use another notations, hexadecimal for example:

```
head simhash.txt | perl -F/\\x20/ -lane 'print $F[1]'
```

Comment: in this case argument of -F is regexp `/\x20/`